# AWS S3 JAVA SDK - listObjects returns incomplete directory listings

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When i use the listObjects() method, AWS returns a list of files and folders similar to this:

```
root/
root/projects/
root/projects/101/
root/projects/102/
root/projects/102/file1.pdf
root/images/image1.png
root/images/image2.png
root/favicon.ico
```

My results are not being truncated, and I'm wondering why it doesn't return a record for root/images/
I am not using the delimiter feature.

Answer (score 0):

If You use as following, The List Object will have all  the objects in the S3 Bucket.
ListObjectsRequest lor = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName("myBucket");
ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(lor);

If you want to have only objects in a specified directory as you said root/images, you need to specify as

ListObjectsRequest lor = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName("myBucket").withPrefix("image/");

Hope it helps

Comment: I believe the question is about why the root/images folder doesn't show up on its own line, whereas root/projects for example does. I haven't seen this behavior but I'd be curious to know as well.